# Quickblox: Sample won' start

Tags: java, android, eclipse, quickblox

So i am trying to run the `Quickblox` [sample chat](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-chat) and [XMPP Sample Chat](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample).

Im using Eclipse with the newest Android sdk/build.

After importing the sample, the way the Quickblox guide tells, i had a few errors in the in the code, but not much more than a few imports missing, but when im trying to run the app i get an error, the app installs correct but right after errors starts popping in on Logcat.

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity implements QBCallback {

private static final String APP_ID = "6445";
private static final String AUTH_KEY = "9a4bnSXbP-KN9G8";
private static final String AUTH_SECRET = "FwunQpKdkE2e7AJ";

private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);



    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit(APP_ID, AUTH_KEY, AUTH_SECRET);
    QBAuth.createSession(this);
}

@Override
public void onComplete(Result result) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Error(s) occurred. Look into DDMS log for details, " +
                "please. Errors: " + result.getErrors()).create().show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onComplete(Result result, Object context)
{
}
}
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

private static final int AUTHENTICATION_REQUEST = 1;
private static final int POSITION_USER = 0;
private static final int POSITION_ROOM = 1;
private SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private Action lastAction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    List<Fragment> tabs = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    tabs.add(UsersFragment.getInstance());
    tabs.add(RoomsFragment.getInstance());

    sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabs);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < sectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(sectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
     }
  }

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    int position = tab.getPosition();
    QBUser qbUser = ((App) getApplication()).getQbUser();
    if (qbUser != null) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

    } else if (position == POSITION_ROOM) {
        lastAction = Action.ROOM_LIST;
        showAuthenticateDialog();
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (lastAction) {
            case CHAT:
                ((UsersFragment) sectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(POSITION_USER)).startChat();
                break;
            case ROOM_LIST:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(POSITION_ROOM);
                break;
        }
        ((RoomsFragment) sectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(POSITION_ROOM)).loadRooms();
    } else {
        showUsersFragment();
    }
}

private void showUsersFragment() {
    getSupportActionBar().selectTab(getSupportActionBar().getTabAt(POSITION_USER));
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(POSITION_USER);
}

public void setLastAction(Action lastAction) {
    this.lastAction = lastAction;
}

public void showAuthenticateDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Authorize first");
    builder.setItems(new String[]{"Login", "Register"}, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which) {
                case 0:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, AUTHENTICATION_REQUEST);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, AUTHENTICATION_REQUEST);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            showUsersFragment();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

public static enum Action {CHAT, ROOM_LIST}

public static class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case POSITION_USER:
                return "Users";
            case POSITION_ROOM:
                return "Rooms";
        }
        return null;
    }
}}
```

My manifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.quickblox.sample.chat"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.quickblox.sample.chat.ui.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINMENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.ChatActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.LoginActivity"
        android:label="Login" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.RegistrationActivity"
        android:label="Registration" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

This is my error message:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.quickblox.sample.chat/com.quickblox.sample.chat.ui.activities.SplashActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.quickblox.sample.chat.ui.activities.SplashActivity
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
```

Answer (score 1):

Open Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export and check QB jar library. According to logs you haven't added it to the build.

Answer (score 1):

1) First of all make sure that you have imported "quickblox-android-1.2.2.jar" which comes with QuickBlox SDK in folder named jar then just Right click on project -> Properties -> Got to Java Build Path -> Order and Export -> just check quickblox-android-1.2.2.jar(which is unchecked in list) -> click Ok.

2)Just Clean the project and run it.

Note:- If you do not clean the project after step 1 then project will crash so clean the project before running it.